# Count a number of records in a field using awk

Tags: awk, count

I have a big file like this one

```
C1,C2,C3
C1,C2
C5
C3,C5
```

I expected one output like this

```
C1,C2,C3   3
C1,C2      2
C5         1
C3,C5      2
```

I would like to make this using shell. Could you help me guys, please? 
Thankyou

Comment: What have you done so far??

Comment: "Fields in a record", no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{printf "%-20s\t%d\n",$0,NF;}' file
```

should give

```
C1,C2,C3                3
C1,C2                   2
C5                      1
C3,C5                   2
```

<sup>**Note** You need to adjust the width logically considering the maximum length of your lines</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk '{
    m=(m<(n=length($0))?n:m)                  # get the max record length
    a[NR]=$0 }                                # hash to a
END {
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)                        # iterate and (below) output nicely
        printf "%s%"(m-length(a[i])+4)"s\n",a[i],gsub(/,/,"&",a[i])+1 }
' file
C1,C2,C3   3
C1,C2      2
C5         1
C3,C5      2
```

IF you want to change the distance between fields and the length, toy with that `+4` in the `printf`.